# Trying to put user input in yahoo api URL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to learn ios and my first project is to make an app that displays weather forecast in the area the of the zip code the user enters.

I have the url which is:

```
NSString *zipUrl = @"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2289448%22&format=json";
```

The zip code is near the end after 3D%22:

> 3D%22**89448**%22

I just need to figure out how to insert what the user entered in a text box into this spot. I have tried `[NSString StringWithFormat]` but there are to many % signs that it doesn't work.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode zipUrl first because it encoded string.

```
NSString *zipUrl = @"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2289448%22&format=json";

    NSString *decodedString= [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",zipUrl] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"decodedString : %@",decodedString);

    NSString *myStringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select item from weather.forecast where location=%@&format=json",yourtextfield.text];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter/add/put value from user input by `%@` sign, such like

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/userInput=%@",textFiled.text];
```

And also use [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a) for convert your URL to `legal URL`

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL_STRING"];
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```